# crosstool-ng how to add extra libraries to cross compiler toolchain for debian

Tags: debian, cross-compiling, crosstool-ng

I'm trying to create a cross compile tool with crosstool-ng 1.25 and everything seems to work but I can't add extra libraries.
The issue here is that I can't find a way to add extra packages to the toolchain. In this specific scenario I need the package "libiw-dev" since the application I'm trying to compile uses "iwlib.h".
I looked around in the crosstool-ng documentation but can't find any answers on how to achieve this.
Has anyone came across this issue?
This is a custom board running debian, crosstool-ng seemed like a good way to make the cross compile toolchain, but I may consider other tools if they make more sense here. My main goal is to create a cross compiler with the kernel headers, but also with all the libraries the system uses.

I looked at all the options (I think) on "./ct-ng menuconfig", even tried to ask chatgpt but not luck yet